# Retrieve anonymous link on creating item of a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part, anonymous-authentication

I have a classic sharepoint online list, when I create some item in list(create view) I want to retrieve a link of that item I'm currently creating to send email with that link to anonymous person.

My question is. how can I take the link so the user can edit or see that item?
Can I do with a `Content Editor`?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can see the link while creating item as  the item ID is available only after creation and it is required for the view page. However, if viewing while creation is not required then the notification part can be achieved by a designer workflow on item creation.